# Real time AutoResetEvent after async-await continuation in C#

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, task, real-time

I am using C# to control a hardware device. The program is structured as

1. A hardware control thread (normal CPU priority)

   ```
   while (notFinished)
   {
       Prepare();
       await DeviceCommunication();
       autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
   }
   ```
2. A UI thread (normal CPU priority)
3. A heavy computational thread (below normal CPU priority)

There is a layer of device API written in C# `Task`. The `AutoResetEvent` delay after `Task` continuation is sometimes as high as 500ms depending on the state of PC (the heavy computational thread is not even running). It is generally fine except during some critical hardware control moments. It requires 10ms response time.

I tested setting the consumer thread to above normal and mocking the asynchronous function to force it to synchronous. It seemed to solve the problem. However, in the real asynchronous functions, there are `await`. They immediately release the thread. The continuations are in threads from the thread-pool.

---

Question 1

Is the 500ms delay normal? I am using VirtualBox with i5 2 threads. I expect the target PC will perform similarly to mine.

---

Assuming my findings are valid. To solve the problem, my choices are

1. Use `Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` to turn async to sync. It should not cause deadlocks.
2. Rewrite the device API layer to support true sync operations. It is elegant and follows the general rules but they are just nice to have.
3. Set `Task` scheduling priority and CPU priority
4. Use 3rd parties `Task` libraries

---

Question 2

Are there better choices?

---

Question 3
How to do choice 3 (Set `Task` scheduling priority and CPU priority)? Is a custom `TaskScheduler` the only way to do it?

Comment: Is this called from a UI thread? If so, what happens if you try doing `await DeviceCommunication().ConfigureAwait(false);` instead?

Comment: Re Q1 - 500ms is way outside the raw overhead the await state machine typically introduces, which is more in the region of (very roughly) 50uS (i.e. ~10000x quicker) on an average modern laptop.  That 50uS does compare to approximately 0uS for sync, though, and hence async is not a natural choice for high-performance non-I/O tasks.  If you're trying to meet a 10ms goal, though, I doubt the native async-await overhead is what's getting in the way; it will be something else.  What is the UI here (console / Winforms / WPF)?

Comment: It does not continue in the UI thread. The continuation is on the thread from thread-pool. Actually, there is a WCF layer separating the UI. I have corrected the description of my problem. Sorry for the confusion. The await state machine overhead should not be the problem. The problem should be CPU scheduling.

Comment: Who and when is responsible of setting the autoResetEvent?

Comment: Please note that the sync `WaitOne()` call is going to block a thread-pool thread (something you normally want to avoid if possible). I suggest taking a look at [Stephen Cleary's  Nito library](https://github.com/StephenClearyArchive/Nito.Asynchronous); there is an async `AutoResetEvent` version available as well as many other helpful async primitives.

Comment: Just to understand better, are you experiencing the 500 ms continuation response  time AFTER you have set the event?

Comment: The `AutoResetEvent` is set by another normal CPU priority thread. The code blocking a thread-pool thread is temporary. Async version of `AutoResetEvent` is the proper one if the code is fully async-await.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not provide any scheduling guarantees of any kind. Period. We frequently see extra delays of several seconds for C# code on a Win7 system while device drivers are busy. If you really have a hard real time requirement, you need to be running on an RTOS.

Comment: On the other hand, games, movies and songs play just fine. They do that by using schedule priorities and the [multimedia class scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/multimedia-class-scheduler-service?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Several second delays are *humongous*. If you see several seconds of delays, it's not the OS that is at fault. RTOS doesn't mean no delay, it means refusing to even start a task that can't be completed within its constraints. That requires specialized programming too.

Comment: @Panagiotis: _"movies and songs play just fine"_ -- _most_ of the time. There are plenty of ways to cause video and audio playback to stutter/fragment/etc. on Windows, or any other mainstream OS. There are limits even to the multimedia API.

Comment: I know. I even remember the time it was a 16-bit process to ensure it got guaranteed scheduling. RTOS has little to do with this question. I'll also repeat that if you get second-long delays you have bad driver problems.  *Especially* when you work with with specialized device vendors - the pressure to write good device drivers just isn't there. They make no money from them and their volumes aren't so great that they'd be humiliated out of the market if the drivers were slow.

Comment: In fact, I remember the *months* it took to convince FTDI that its serial-over-ethernet drivers didn't handle handshakes properly. *Their* samples, that used manual handshaking, worked. I had to point them to the MSDN doc sample that *clearly* couldn't work with their driver even though it worked with everyone else's devices.